# Redirect logged user depending on user role if he tries to access home page?

Tags: functions

I want to redirect every user, depending on its user role, who wants to access home page (its my welcome login page).

I don't want to redirect users just after they log in, but after they are logged in and if they maybe again access home page incidentally.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) is documented, as are functions such as [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Also read about **wp_redirect()** too.

```
function redirect_by_role(){
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (is_home()) {
      if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
         $redirect_url= '';
         wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301); exit;
      }
      elseif( in_array( '**another_role_here**', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
         $redirect_url= '';
         wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301); exit;
      }
    }

  } else { 
   // Do what you want

  }
}
// Add the action with maximum priority
add_action('init','redirect_by_role',0);
```

Comment: Thanks Sabbir, but it doesnt look like its working. I logged as such user and it wont redirect me when I access home page, even I changed user roles and redirection urls.

Comment: please try now again

Comment: Thanks again Sabbir, but its still the same. Don't know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Vucko, try to change `init` hook to `wp` this way:

```
function redirect_by_role(){
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (is_home()) {
      if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
         $redirect_url= '';
         wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301); exit;
      }
      elseif( in_array( '**another_role_here**', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
         $redirect_url= '';
         wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301); exit;
      }
    }

  } else { 
   // Do what you want

  }
}
// Add the action with maximum priority
add_action('wp','redirect_by_role');
```

`is_home()` function is not working on `init` hook. It start works after `parse_query`. You can see hooks priority [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)